# Is there another way to put each of this div to 33% width in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
* {
      margin:0;
    }
    #container {
      height:800px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content:space-between;
      background-color:grey;
    }


    #box-1 {
      background-color:green;
      height:400px;
      flex:1
     

    }
    #box-2 {
      background-color:yellow;
      height:200px;
      flex:1;
    }
    #box-3 {
      background-color:pink;
      height:100px;
      flex:1;

    }
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="box-1"></div>
    <div id="box-2"></div>
    <div id="box-3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can someone tell me if there's another way to  put every div to 33% div so I wouldn't need to re calculate it each time I've added some margin/padding? I was wondering if there's anything I missed while learning flexbox.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you searching for `flex-direction:row;`?

Comment: I don't understand what's your purpose. Do you want to put the colored divs next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `flex-direction:row;` see below:-

```css
* {
      margin:0;
    }
    #container {
      height:800px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content:space-between;
      background-color:grey;
   flex-direction:row;
    }


    #box-1 {
      background-color:green;
      height:400px;
      flex:1
     

    }
    #box-2 {
      background-color:yellow;
      height:200px;
      flex:1;
    }
    #box-3 {
      background-color:pink;
      height:100px;
      flex:1;

    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box-1"></div>
    <div id="box-2"></div>
    <div id="box-3"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you need 33% **width** (horizontal length) for the three `div` items, the container class needs `flex-direction: row;` instead of `flex-direction: column;`. The three `div` items will fill up the device width equally (33.3%)
- if you meant 33% **height** (vertical length) for the three `div` items, you can add `flex-basis: 33.3%;` property to your `box` classes.